# How to use Injected Environment Variables in Extended Email in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I have a pipeline, in which I am injecting environment variables through a groovy file in the build stage in following manner:

```
stage('Test-Mail') {
       agent {
              label 'master'
            }
             steps {
                 load '..\\..\\EnvVars.groovy'
                 script {
                   echo bat(returnStdout: true, script: 'set')
                 }
           }
    }
```

When I'm printing all the environment variables by the echo command, I'm able to see all the variables default as well as injected ones successfully.

But when I tried to use them in the post build event inside Extended Email's body, I'm unable to get the value. I tried to echo the value in post build too, and I'm able to get the value there.

I tried the Extended Email in below manner:

```
post {
     always {
     bat ' echo BUILD_VERSION=%BUILD_VERSION%'
     emailext body: '''$PROJECT_NAME - $BUILD_DISPLAY_NAME -  ${BUILD_VERSION}  $BUILD_NUMBER - $BUILD_STATUS.
Follow the below links for details:
 Job URL: $JOB_URL
 Console Output : $BUILD_URL
                 
Regards,''', subject: 'Test Email Notification From Jenkins', to: 'vishalp@gmail.com'
                  
        }
    }
```

The variable **BUILD_VERSION** is injected from the groovy file.

I tried with:

> $BUILD_VERSION

> ${BUIILD_VERSOIN}

> ${env.BUILD_VERSION}

> ${ENV, var="BUILD_VERSION"}

But nothing seems working.

The mail body I am receiving looks like:

```
POCs » Mail-Notification-Pipeline - #34 -  ${BUILD_VERSION}  34 - Successful.

Follow the below links for details:
 Job URL: http://172.16.1.73:8080/job/POCs/job/Mail-Notification-Pipeline/
 Console Output : http://172.16.1.73:8080/job/POCs/job/Mail-Notification-Pipeline/34/

Regards,
```

I'm able to access all the default environment variables provided by Jenkins, But not the ones I injected.
Are there different kinds of environment variables do Jenkins have? Am I using the variable in wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change simple quotes `'''` with double quotes `"""`.
As per the [Groovy documentation](https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_triple_single_quoted_string):

> Triple-single-quoted strings are plain java.lang.String and don’t support interpolation.

Comment: I tried as you said, and now I'm getting error as:
 
 `Error when executing always post condition:
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: PROJECT_NAME for class: WorkflowScript
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:53)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.getProperty(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:458)...`

Comment: If `'''` doesn't support interpolation, then how come **$PORJECT_NAME** , **$BUILD_NUMBER**, etc are working fine?

Comment: The error is due to `PROJECT_NAME` variable being out of scope, as it was declared (loaded) inside a stage, it's not visible in the post block. As per the `'''` issue is a bit weird, maybe you can share the job/email output?

Comment: PROJECT_NAME is the variable provided by Jenkins by default, I have not injected it.
The email output I'm getting for a successful build right now is:  
POCs » Mail-Notification-Pipeline - #34 -  %BUILD_VERSION%  34 - Successful.

Follow the below links for details:

 Job URL: http://172.16.1.73:8080/job/POCs/job/Mail-Notification-Pipeline/

 Console Output : http://172.16.1.73:8080/job/POCs/job/Mail-Notification-Pipeline/34/



Regards,

Comment: You're correct, they're Jenkins global variables, apologies for that. Maybe you can paste the contents of these URLs in the question, like an update? Looks like I'm not able to reach them.